# Should I use the Android Q Beta?

Tags: android-beta-program, android-10

The Android Q Beta has some great features and fixes the bad gesture navigation from before. I would really like to try it. From what I was able to gather, it's mostly fine, but I wasn't able to find a lot of resources detailing the downsides.

What I'm mostly concerned with is errors during the upgrading process, data loss and the running of the four most important apps for me:

1. WhatsApp
2. YouTube (music)
3. Firefox

I have already searched for issues, but wanted to make sure before I do something that could potentially create a huge hassle for me. I'm really thankful for any advice in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general productive usage of beta versions provided by Google is not recommended.

Google provides beta versions of upcoming Android versions for developers. Using the beta versions they are able to check if their apps will be compatible with the upcoming Android versions. Also developers can use those images to make some first test with upcoming new features.

Therefore I would strongly suggest to wait for the official release, especially if the apps that are important to you don't explicitly state that they are Android Q compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I have decided to wait, as you recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wait until the official release of android q is made by Google because if you use it now you can get many errors while making an android app